# Meteor: Applying the onCreated callback to all templates

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to run some code on the onCreated event in meteor in every template.

I know meteor allows helpers to apply to all templates:

```
Template.registerHelper("example", function() {
  // do something
});
```

But is it possible to register a function that will apply to every onCreated event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a package like [template-extension](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension):

```
meteor add aldeed:template-extension
```

Then you can do [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension#templateoncreated--templateonrendered--templateondestroyed):

```
Template.onCreated(function () {
  // do something
});
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. Aldeed does some amazing things for Meteor.